# User defined type guard is not changing the type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Not sure whats going on here, Im running my array of objects through a type guard, And if it is of length 3 then I want to assert it to be of a different type (tuple), But for some reason typescript is not recognising the new type I have assigned to it.

```
interface squareType {
  value: string,
}

// Defining a tuple which will allow us to set a max length of each row
type rowTuple = [squareType, squareType, squareType]

// define a 3*3 grid
type gridTuple = [rowTuple, rowTuple, rowTuple]

function isRowTuple(possibleRow: squareType[]): possibleRow is rowTuple {
  return (possibleRow.length === 3) ? true : false
}

// type guard to check if it is a grid tuple
function isGridTuple(possibleGrid: rowTuple[]): possibleGrid is gridTuple {
  // check if the length is correct
  return true
}
function App() {
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState<gridTuple | undefined>()
  // build a grid
  useEffect(() => {
    let grid: rowTuple[] = []
    for (let y = 1; y <= 3; y++) {
      let row: squareType[] = []
      for (let x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
        let sq: squareType;
        sq = {
          value: 'kudos',
        }
        row.push(sq)
      }
      // change type of row to rowTuple
      isRowTuple(row)
      grid.push(row) // error is here
    }
  }, [])
```

The error is squareType[] is not assignable to row tuple, target requires 3 elements but source may have fewer.

However I have checked and 'row' does have 3 elements and the call to the type guard does return true

Comment: You need to use a type guard with an if statement. `if (isRowTuple(row)) { grid.push(row) }`

Comment: You'll need to place your grid.push(row) inside of an if block. In your code this line is reached in all cases, not only if isRowTuple is true, so nothing ensures it's of the right type.

Comment: At compile (eg transpile) time, the size of `row` is unknown. You could try using `let row: rowTuple;`